# R - cannot install packages

Tags: r, installation

I am having trouble installing R packages, e.g. ggalluvial or ggbeeswarm.

Here is an the output I get:

```
> install.packages("ggalluvial")
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Installiere Paket nach ‘C:/Users/SK/Documents/R/win-library/4.1’
(da ‘lib’ nicht spezifiziert)
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘ggalluvial’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1:
  cannot open URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/PACKAGES'
```

Here is my sessioninfo:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252    LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.1.2 tools_4.1.2
```

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Is your computer connected to the internet? Can you go to http://cran.rstudio.com/ in your web browser? It sounds like your access to the CRAN repository is being blocks so you cannot download any R packages.

Comment: Hi! Try closing R, then open again, update all R packages and use `install.packages('ggalluvial', repos = 'https://cloud.r-project.org/')` just for testing.

Comment: Are you using a firewall? Do you have issues installing other packages? You can check if changing the repository solves the problem, e.g,  `install.packages('ggalluvial', repos = 'https://cran.wu.ac.at/')`

Comment: Yes, I have full access to the internet. Not using a firewall. I can access https://cran.rstudio.com/ through my browser without any issues. I restarted R and ran this command ```install.packages('ggalluvial', repos = 'https://cloud.r-project.org/')```, which gave me the same output as above.

Comment: For some reason R can't access http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES and if it can't access that URL then it can't install packages. You do have R locally installed on your computer, right? Is this a work computer? Perhaps you can contact your IT department to see if they've done anything that might block R's access to CRAN. Every other time I've seen a problem like this it's always been a network configuration issue and not an issue with R itself.